# css footer doesn't remain at the end of the content

Tags: html, css

I have a website and I want to put a footer at the end of each page.

The page `login` has content, but the footer doesn't remain at the end of it.

#### login

```
<div class="login">
    <form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo URL; ?>Login/run">
        <li>
            <label>
                Username:
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="username"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                Password:
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="password"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                Type:
            </label>
            <select name="typeOfUser">
                <option  value="1">Restaurant</option>
                <option value="2">Customer</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label></label>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </li>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### css

```
.login{
    position: relative;top: 100px;
    margin-left: 280px;
}
.login li{
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.login label{
    color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
.login input{
    padding: 0.4em;
}
.login select{
    padding: 0.4em;
}
```

[image: my rendered HTML page]

footer

```
#footerContent{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: #646467;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `login div` css to

```
.login{

position: relative;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: 280px;
}
```

and footer will come after login div.

[Check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NIkhar/9Xcrr/)

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#footerContent{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 48px;
background-color: #646467;
}
```

Comment: this link somewhat help u http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page